# Convert a 2D array to a 1D array

Tags: excel, vba

How do I work around the *255 characters per cell* limit when converting a range (= multidimensional array) to single dimensional array with the use of `Application.Index(array, row, column)`?

The following truncated example reproduces the error:

> Error 13. Type mismatch

(The complete code is on [superuser where I tried to help another user](https://superuser.com/a/978282/50173)).

#### How to reproduce

- Open a new Excel sheet and insert the formula `=REPT("x",256)` to cell A1
  This creates a 256 characters long string which is just 1 character too long for the last step
- Open the VBA editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) and paste the below code somewhere
- Execute the code line by line with <kbd>F8</kbd>

  ```
  Function StringLengthTest()       
      Dim arr2D As Variant
      Dim arr1D As Variant        
      arr2D = Rows(1)
      arr1D = Application.Index(arr2D, 1, 0)        
  End Function
  ```
- You'll see the same error at the last line when Excel tries to convert a range (2D) to a 1D array while one of its cells has more than 255 characters.

To prove this, change `=REPT("x",256)` to `=REPT("x",255)` and run the code again. This time it will work.

**Question:** Should I declare my variables in another way? Is there a better way to convert a range (which is always a 2D object at first) to a single dimensional array?

I know I could use a loop to iterate through the arrays and save all 2D array values one by one to a 1D array. But that's not efficient. Imagine really large sheets.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot work with `arr2D` as a 2D array specifying **1** in the first rank? `arr2D(1, v)` would be equal to `arr1D(v)`.

Comment: btw, that would be `LBound(arr2D , 2)` and `UBound(arr2D , 2)` for the extents.

Comment: Looping will be about twice as fast as using INDEX() here

Comment: Why bother converting? As @Jeeped pointed out, you don't need to, and any conversion/copy wastes time and space.

Comment: HAHA... tried it with `Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Rows(1)))` => same behavior... `=REPT("x",256)` pops up an error :D

Comment: @Jeeped as shown in the link, he is giong to do use `Join`... knowing he'll do that => `For Each ...` & `string = string & [delimeter] & [Each]` will be much faster... however... at least, it doesn't answer the question...

Answer (score 1):

by far the best way of getting anything from a cells into memory (an array) is to use an array variant. I think the problem you are having is with index not with your method.

Hopefully this code should explain it.

```
Dim v_data As Variant
Dim rw As Long, cl As Long ' for row and column
Dim arr1d() As Variant
Dim count As Long

' I'm going to use UsedRange to get the whole sheet  .UsedSheet
' If you just want things from one row or column then just spec
' activesheet.range("A1:A100") or use cells()
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  ReDim v_data(1 To .Rows.count, 1 To .Columns.count)
  v_data = .Value
End With

'now we have all the things from that sheet.
'so to convert to 1d array where the cell value is say = 1
For rw = LBound(v_data) To UBound(v_data)
   For cl = LBound(v_data, 2) To UBound(v_data, 2) ' note the comma 2 for the second dimension bounds.
       If v_data(rw, cl) = 1 Then
           count = count + 1
           ReDim Preserve arr1d(1 To count)
           arr1d(count) = v_data(rw, cl)
       End If
   Next cl
Next rw

For count = LBound(arr1d) To UBound(arr1d)
    Debug.Print arr1d(count)
Next count
```

now the trick is to farm this off to a function that takes a few args( a 2d range, what you are looking for in that range) and returns your list.

To get your data back into a workbook

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(arr1d), 1).Value = arr1d
```

make a range of the exact same size in terms of the bounds of your array and then ensuring you use `.value` just pop in the variant array.